# How do you make npm install locally?

Tags: windows, npm

NPM will not install packages locally, update package.json, nor update package.lock. It's a very perplexing issue honestly.
Pseudo-steps to reproduce are:

1. mkdir testFolder
2. cd testFolder
3. npm init -> use defaults
4. npm install dotenv

I'm running Windows 11.

- I tried running with Developer mode on and off
- I tried installing node (16.15.1)/npm via NVM4W (1.1.9) and using `npm install <package>`
- I uninstalled NVM4W and installed node (18.4.0) directly

I'm kind of at a loss for things to try now.
It feels like there's some Windows setting somewhere I'm missing that's causing all these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it turned out that I had modified my C:\Users{user}.npmrc file which had the setting "location=global" set. I deleted the setting and it all worked.

This got set, I believe, because I did npm config set local=global earlier due to a deprecation warning I received using an older version of npm.